# How to execute a method only after each http request succeeds in scrapy spider?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, twisted

I have following spider:

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import defer

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # deferred = defer.Deferred()
        # deferred.addCallback(self.parse_author)
        # deferred.addCallback(self.process_engine)
        self.logger.info("Parsing quote page!!")
        data = {}
        quotes = response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]')
        for i, quote in enumerate(quotes):
            data['quote'] = quote.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').get()
            data['tags'] = quote.xpath('.//div[@class="tags"]/a[@class="tag"]/text()').getall()
            data['author_url'] = response.urljoin(quote.xpath('.//a[starts-with(@href, "/author/")]/@href').get())
            if data['author_url'] and i < 5:
                yield scrapy.Request(data['author_url'], callback=self.parse_author, meta={'data': data})
                # yield scrapy.Request(data['author_url'], callback=deferred.callback)
            else:
                self.logger.info("Author data not found!!")
                yield data

        if quotes:
            self.process_engine()


    def parse_author(self, response):
        self.logger.info("Parsing author page!!")
        data = response.meta.get('data')
        data['author_name'] = response.xpath('//h3/text()').get()
        data['author_dob'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="author-born-date"]/text()').get()
        yield data

    def process_engine(self, data=None):
        self.logger.info("\n<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< process engine running >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n")
        # some logic here
```

What I want here is to execute *process_engine* method only after each *start_urls* requests finishes successfully(i.e. there are *quotes* which may be stored in a **database**). But what is happening here is that while **spider** is waiting to **fetch** *author_url* data, *process_engine* method gets executed.
I tried using **defer** too, but didn't work or I didn't do it right way. How can we resolve this problem? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry it’s not clear to me what you are trying to achieve here? The callbacks are what are executed after a successful request...

Comment: Hi @tomjn *what is happening here is that while spider is waiting to fetch author_url data, process_engine method gets executed*

Comment: Hi @tomjn, *what is happening here is that while spider is waiting to fetch author_url data in 2nd yield scrapy.Request() (parse method), process_engine method(outside the loop) gets executed*. But I don't want *process_engine* method to be executed unless all the responses are fetched for the particular start_url i.e. unless the loop completes and also author data are fetched.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want to do in `process_engine`? The answer might be different depending on what you want to do